# spark scala: extracting xml from one column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Assume `df` has the following structure:

```
root
 |-- id: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

here `text` contains strings of roughly-XML type records. I'm then able to apply the following steps to extract the necessary entries into a flat table:

First, append the root node, since there is none originally. (Question #1: is this step necessary, or can be omitted?)

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("text", concat(lit("<root>"),$"text",lit("</root>")))
```

Next, parsing the XML:

```
val payloadSchema = schema_of_xml(df.select("text").as[String])
val df3 = spark.read.option("rootTag","root").option("rowTag","row").schema(payloadSchema)xml(df2.select("text").as[String])
```

This generates `df3`:

```
root
 |-- row: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

which I finally explode:

```
val df4 = df3.withColumn("exploded_cols", explode($"row"))
```

into

```
root
 |-- row: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_cols: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

My goal is the following table:

```
val df5 = df4.select("exploded_cols.*")
```

with

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

---

**Main question:**
I want that the final table would also contain the `id: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)` entries along with the exploded `key, value` columns, e.g.,

```
root
 |-- id: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

however, I'm not sure how to call `spark.read.option` without selecting `df2.select("text").as[String]` separately into the method (see `df3`). Is it possible to simplify this script?

This should be straightforward, so I'm not sure a reproducible example is necessary. Also, I'm coming blind from an [r](/questions/tagged/r) background, so I'm missing all the scala basics, but trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from_xml` function of [spak-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) library.

```
val df = // Read source data
val schema = // Define schema of XML text

df.withColumn("xmlData", from_xml("xmlColName", schema))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: As a side question, is there any downside in general for defining separate objects for any intermediate step in the code, e.g., ``val df1= ...``, ``val df2=...`` and so on, instead of piping all the steps together? I know that, for example, in [tag:R], each separate object definition allocates a lot of unnecessary space -- is it the same with scala as well? Or does the compile handle all these in runtime? Hope this question makes sense

Comment: Could you please put it as another question? I don't know the proper researched answer for this.